# Citing in a research paper when the citation is based on an published interview

Tags: citations

What is the correct way to quote a person in an academic research paper when that person has said something in an interview? Many professors are considered as experts on their own fields, and hence are often interview by news papers on recent events that are related to their research. If I want to quote this professor in my research paper for what he has said in his comments in the published interview, and want to do so on multiple ocations, what is the correct way to quote after the first occasion, i.e. am I right in writing Professor X (2016), when in fact the source where Professor X has given his comment is written by Reporter Y, or is it enough to simply give the link to the original source in the references section?

Answer (score 1):

Citing an interview is pretty standard, though every citation style will format it a little differently.  For example, [here is how it is done in MLA style](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/09/).  A little Googling will find it for any other style that you may happen to be using.